# How to make both `x` and `y` axises look in same scale?

Tags: plotting

Plot the equation `y = 2x - 7`, where `x` goes from `-10` to `10`.

```
Plot[2x-7,{x,-10,10}]
```

output:
[image]

**Question:** On image `x` axis looks more elongated than `y` axis (contain more values on image length). How to make both `x` and `y` axises look in same scale?

Comment: add the option `AspectRatio ->1`?

Comment: @kglr  This `Plot[2 x - 7, {x, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1]` changes the aspect ratio but it makes `5` on `x` looks like `10` on `y`. How to make them equal?

Comment: `Plot[2 x - 7, {x, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]`

Comment: maybe `Plot[2 x - 7, {x, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {-10,10}]` or ``Plot[2 x - 7, {x, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-10,10}]``?

Comment: @LouisB It works. Thank you.

Comment: @kglr Both variant worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plot[2 x - 7, {x, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

or

```
Plot[2 x - 7, {x, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

both give

[image]